# why google map re render when i am click on marker icon map is re render again and again in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

why google map re render  when i am click on marker icon map is re render again and again in react js even also i have used React.memo but still it is re render on marker click.what should i do??

this is my code

```
// import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import AllPatient from '../components/patient/AllPatient'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import {
  MenuIcon,
  SearchIcon,
  ShoppingCartIcon,
  PlusSmIcon,
  LogoutIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import useSWR from 'swr';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps";
import AlertBox from '../components/patient/AlertBox'
import axios from "axios";

const fetcher = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/patient`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

const Patient = React.memo(function Patient(props) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    router.push('/add-patient')
  }


  const hundlerender = () => {
    mutate()
  }


  const mapRef = React.useRef();
  const onMapLoad = React.useCallback((map) => {
    mapRef.current = map;

  }, [])

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [delID, steDelID] = useState('')

  const deleteRecord = () => {
    axios({
      method: "DELETE",
      url: `/api/patient`,
      data: {
        id: delID,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setOpen(false);
        hundlerender()

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setOpen(true);
        console.log(error);

      });

  }


  const deletePatient = (id) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOpen(true);
    steDelID(id);


  }

  const { data, mutate, error } = useSWR('patient', fetcher);


  const [defaultCenter, setDefaultCenter] = React.useState({ lat: parseFloat(data?.patients[0].lat), lng: parseFloat(data?.patients[0].lng) });
  console.log(data?.patients[0].lat)
  const defaultOptions = { scrollwheel: false };


  const [latLng, setLatLng] = React.useState();

  const [key, setKey] = React.useState("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + process.env.MAP_KEY);

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    isOpen: false
  });


  const handleToggle = (e) => {
    setState({
      isOpen: !state.isOpen
    });
  }

  const displayMarkers = () => {
    return data.patients.map((row, index) => {

      //  setDefaultCenter({lat: row.lat, lng: row.lng});
      if (typeof row.lat !== "undefined" && typeof row.lng !== "undefined") {
        return <Marker position={{ lat: parseFloat(row.lat), lng: parseFloat(row.lng) }}

          name="My Marker"
          color="blue" key={row._id}
          onClick={handleToggle}>
          {state.isOpen &&
            <InfoWindow
              onCloseClick={handleToggle}
            >
              <span>{row.address1}</span>
            </InfoWindow>
          }
        </Marker>
      }


    })
  }
  console.log(defaultCenter)
  const RegularMap = withScriptjs(
    withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={8}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: parseFloat(data?.patients[0].lat), lng: parseFloat(data?.patients[0].lng) }}
        defaultOptions={defaultOptions}
        onLoad={onMapLoad}
      >

        {
          displayMarkers()
        }


        {console.log('map re render')}
      </GoogleMap>
    ))
  );

  const loadingElementStyle = { height: '100%' };
  const containerElementStyle = { height: '280px' };
  const mapElementStyle = { height: '100%' };








  // const {data,  mutate , error} = useSWR('patient', fetcher);
  // const [defaultCenter, setDefaultCenter] = React.useState({lat: ((data.patients).length == 0) ? 'There is no patients please add a patients' : parseFloat(data.patients[0].lat)  ,lng: ((data.patients).length == 0) ? 'There is no patients' :  parseFloat(data.patients[0].lng)  });

  if (error) return 'An error has occured'
  if (!data) return 'Loading'
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex-shrink-0">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-400 shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
          onClick={handleClick} >
          <PlusSmIcon
            className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5"
            aria-hidden="true"
          />
          <span>New Patient</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      {/* <AllPatient data={data} hundlerender={hundlerender}/> */}


      <div>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <AlertBox open={open} setOpen={setOpen} deleteRecord={deleteRecord} />
          <div className="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
            <div className="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
              <div className="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
                <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                  <thead className="bg-gray-50">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        First Name
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        Last Name
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        Address1
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        Address2
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        City
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        State
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        Zip
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        Mobile
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" className="relative px-6 py-3">
                        <span className="sr-only">Action</span>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody className="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    {
                      data.patients.map((row, index) => {
                        return (<tr>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{row.firstName}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{row.lastName}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{row.address1}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                            <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{row.address2}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                            <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{row.city}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                            <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{row.state}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                            <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{row.zip}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                            <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{row.mobile}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              onClick={() => {
                                router.push({
                                  pathname: '/edit-patient',
                                  query: { id: row._id },
                                })
                              }}
                            >
                              Edit
                            </button>

                            <button
                              type="button"
                              onClick={() => deletePatient(row._id)}
                            >
                              &nbsp;Delete
                            </button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        );
                      })}

                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          {(data.patients.length) == 0 ? <h1 className='font-bold text-center mt-10'>There is no patients in the Queue</h1> : <RegularMap
            googleMapURL={key}
            loadingElement={<div style={loadingElementStyle} />}
            containerElement={<div style={containerElementStyle} />}
            mapElement={<div style={mapElementStyle}
            />}
          />}
        </div>
      </div>




    </>
  )
});

export default React.memo(Patient)
```

please give me the solution to stop re rendering  google map.i have already do my best for it nothing is working on it